# Create user registration using stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, user-registration

I am trying to create user registration stored procedure in mysql but I am getting an error.

**Query**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`sp_register`(fullname VARCHAR(50), Mob VARCHAR(10), Email VARCHAR(50), pass VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = Email)
    THEN SET s = 'User already exists';
ELSE
    INSERT INTO users(`name`,`mobile`,`email`,`password`,`created_at`) 
        VALUES(fullname,Mob, Email, pass,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
        THEN SET s =  "User Registered"; 
END IF;


END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a "THEN" statement in an ELSE block

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = Email) THEN
    SET s = 'User already exists';
ELSE
    INSERT INTO users(`name`,`mobile`,`email`,`password`,`created_at`) 
      VALUES(fullname,Mob, Email, pass,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    SET s =  "User Registered"; 
END IF;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew answered, you don't need the "THEN".
You're also missing a semi-colon after the INSERT.